# file input throws an error when form is submitted

Tags: php, html

I run into a problem when trying to upload images to the server using a symfony form as follows:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($image)
    ->add('full', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Imagen', 'multiple' => true))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Guardar'))
    ->getForm();
```

Then in the html:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}                        
{{ form_row(form.full) }}
{{ form_end(form)  }}
```

When I inspect the html I get:

```
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                       
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label required" for="form_full">Imagen</label>
        <input type="file" id="form_full" name="form[full][]" required="required" multiple="multiple" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]" class="btn-default btn">Guardar</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="vZjUzyZCsbsx5TmfWiljncIi1pPymfod_jezOOKgK_k" />
</form>
```

When I get the value of the file in the controller I have this:

```
originalName="myPicture.jpg"
mimeType="image/jpeg"
size=8450
erro=0
*SplFileInfo*pathName="E:\xamp\tmp\php51B5.tmp"
*SplFileInfo*fileName="php51B5.tmp"
```

So far, well, but in other cases of other images with the same format (jpeg), it happens that I get this:

```
originalName="myPicture.jpg"
mimeType="application/octet-stream"
size=0
erro=1
*SplFileInfo*pathName=""
*SplFileInfo*fileName=""
```

As you can see it does not recognize the Mimetype that should be image / jpeg, and it shows that an error occurs but it does not say which one?

Comment: `erro=1` See [the manual of all the daft places to look](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) and the error is `Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RiggsFolly said, the problem is that the `error = 1` means that the file you are trying to upload is larger than the limit set in the `php.ini` of the server, changing this parameter is solved:

*php.ini:*

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=8M
```